# how do I speed up netbeans' localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, glassfish, localhost, performance

I've just switched from radrails to netbeans. So far, so good. But I have noticed that radrails used to serve up pages a lot faster on localhost. I've left the server on glassfish, what can I do to make it run faster I'm on windows xp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should using normal ruby not jruby. Then it should load immediately.

Change this settings via right clicking on the project->properties->rails->ruby platform

Then click manage and add the (ruby) platform which should be the same as for radrails, I guess. Check this via looking on the ruby version.

(ruby platforms are available from Tools menu, too)